# Azure Event Hub process events indefinitely

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, azure-eventhub

I need to create software that can read events from Azure Event Hub in an infinite way and save them on the db following some logic. The first question I wanted to ask is if such thing is feasible using:

`EventProcessorClient` (or rather `EventProcessor<TPartition>` as I would always like to use the SqlServer for checkpoints instead of an Azure Blob Storage) in a `BackgroundService` as Windows Service and then run it in infinitely and every so many events to checkpoint?
I tried this code reading from a single partition but the application crashes after an exception and the loop ends without continuing to process the events.

```
public class LogConsumerBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private const string EventHubConnectionString =
        "ConnString";
    private const string ConsumerGroup = "ConsGroup";
    
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions SerializerOptions = new()
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };

    private readonly ILogger<LogConsumerBackgroundService> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private int _count;

    public LogConsumerBackgroundService(ILogger<LogConsumerBackgroundService> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Guard.Against.Null(logger);
        Guard.Against.Null(serviceProvider);

        _logger = logger;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var eventHubConsumerClientOptions = new EventHubConsumerClientOptions
            {
                ConnectionOptions =
                {
                    TransportType = EventHubsTransportType.AmqpWebSockets
                }
            };

            await using var consumer = new EventHubConsumerClient(ConsumerGroup, EventHubConnectionString, eventHubConsumerClientOptions);

            var startingPosition = EventPosition.Earliest;

            var partitionIds = await consumer.GetPartitionIdsAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            var partitionId = partitionIds.First();

            var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var repository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await foreach (var receivedEvent in consumer.ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync(partitionId, startingPosition,
                                   CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Some logic to save data on bd

                        _logger.LogInformation("Processed row: {Count}", countInfo += _count);

                        await repository.SaveChangesAsync();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "{EventBody}", receivedEvent.Data?.EventBody);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "Task was canceled");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Demystify(), "An unhandled exception has occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That approach would work; what exception are you seeing? You may want to consider Functions for scalability. Side note: catch `OperationCanceledException` and pass the stopping token to `ReadEventsFromPartitionAsync`.

Comment: I'd suggest that using the processor would be a better approach here, as it is highly resilient and will recover from most exceptions automatically.  If you're going to use the consumer client (or a partition receiver), your application is responsible for handling exceptions, restarting the reads after failures, and tracking the position where readers need to start.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I finally settled on using the EventProcessClient as I need to read from all three partitions and can use blob storage for checkpointing. Now it remains for me to understand how to manage everything because the client is multitasking